# How to replicate existing files using GlusterFS

Tags: glusterfs

I am testing GlusterFS to replicate data across two test servers. I have followed this excellent [step by step Howto](http://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/435-setup-glusterfs-with-a-replicated-volume-over-2-nodes) and everything worked flawlessly.

I have successfully added the peer, created a volume and glusterfs-mounted the gluster volume on a empty mount point. Files touch'ed or copied into that mount point do appear on the peer. No problem here.

But how can I replicate existing data without copying it to a already mounted gluster volume? I have the feeling that I am missing something trivial but what?

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the data off it's current filesystem and onto the gluster filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

Mounting a distributed filesystem, is like creating another partition on your hard disk. The elder partition has your data, while the new one is empty.

Gluster ensures that wherever it is mounted, files will be in sync. 
Like a newly created partition, it doesn't contain anything.

You need to move your stuff to the new "partition" (glusterfs). If you use cp, it's better to use the archive mode in order to preserve timestamps, permissions etc etc.