# How to have two applications accessing a shared drive without isci config or shared lun?

Tags: redhat, vmware-esxi, network-share, cluster, high-availability

We have a 2-node **cluster** configured using red hat **high availability** (pacemaker) but without shared storage i.e. each of the node has its own disk /dev/sda and /dev/sdb.

We are not allowed to configure a **shared LUN (icsi)** for the two nodes to have access to. NFS is also not an option.

Is it safe to format /dev/sdb as gfs2 on node 1 and mount /dev/sdb on node 2 so that if applications writing to both nodes will not corrupt data in /dev/sdb?
If not what's the alternate way to have an active-active solution e.g. through vmware sharing disk if possible maybe?

Note that the 2 nodes are provisioned as virtual machines in vmware.

--Edit:
Using cephfs or glusterfs would require us to configure a separate cluster of at least three nodes which would take us more resources.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replicate existing files using GlusterFS](https://serverfault.com/questions/575676/how-to-replicate-existing-files-using-glusterfs)

Comment: Why do you have so many limitations? Is this a political issue that just requires buy-in and better justification to do it the correct way?

Comment: Do you have shared storage connected to ESXi hosts. Maybe vSAN. Your VMs should have some kind of shared storage to build a red hat cluster. https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2151774

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what kind of solution are you running on your servers, but for example on Oracle RAC linux VM can share a virtual disk enabling [multi-writer](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1034165).
With this option you avoid to use "shared storage" like iscsi or nfs. If you use this solution check that you software is supported with this kind of configuration.